# PHP Streaming CSV always adds UTF-8 BOM

Tags: php, apache, utf-8, csv, byte-order-mark

The following code gets a 'report line' as an array and uses fputcsv to tranform it into CSV. Everything is working great except for the fact that regardless of the charset I use, it is putting a UTF-8 bom at the beginning of the file. This is exceptionally annoying because A) I am specifying iso and B) We have lots of users using tools that show the UTF-8 bom as characters of garbage.

I have even tried writing the results to a string, stripping the UTF-8 BOM and then echo'ing it out and still get it. Is it possible that the issue resides with Apache?
If I change the fopen to a local file it writes it just fine without the UTF-8 BOM.

```
header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"report.csv\"");

$outstream = fopen("php://output",'w');

for($i = 0; $i < $report->rowCount; $i++) {
    fputcsv($outstream, $report->getTaxMatrixLineValues($i), ',', '"');
}
fclose($outstream);

exit;
```

Comment: First, my users are tax people, not tech people. They use what they use and I can't change that.
Second, at this point I am just trying to figure this out for the sake of knowing as I have been fighting with it all day and for the life of me cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess would be that your php source code file has a BOM, and you have php's output buffering enabled.

Comment: Output buffering IS enabled, but the php source code files is in iso-8859-1. When I disable output buffering I get errors that the headers were already sent by the time I get to my first header(..); line, but the only things I have ahead of that are require_once and session_start

Comment: I disabled output buffering, changed some code around, so I wouldn't get headers already sent issues and I'm still getting UTF-8 BOM data on streamed output.

Comment: Chris, thank you for your help! I went through and made sure every file in my project was saved as ASCII. The issue seemed to be that even included files that had UTF-8 BOM data infected the output. With output buffering still enabled, and all the source code files changed to ASCII everything seems to be coming through fine!

Comment: Yup. Even though your text editor may not visually render the BOM, it's there, and php sure sees it. To php, it basically looks like _ï»¿<?php_ which to it, is not different than _hello<?php_

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your problem but have you tried using the print and implode functions to do the same thing?

```
header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"report.csv\"");

for($i = 0; $i < $report->rowCount; $i++) {
    print(implode(',',$report->getTaxMatrixLineValues($i)));
}
```

That's not tested but pretty obvious.

Comment: implode doesn't support quoting strings with commas in. fputscv does.