# PHP outputting CSV files

Tags: php, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have a PHP file which generates both CSV files (download) and HTML files.
When I tried to encode the file to UTF-8 with BOM, the CSV file will be rendered as UTF-8, yet the HTML file will leave 2 rows of spaces.
When I tried to encode the file to UTF-8 without BOM, the CSV file will not be rendered as UTF-8 which causes meaningless codes.
I have tried to add the statement:

```
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
```

Still, the file cannot be read properly. 
P.S. I am not using any of the functions: `fopen,readfile,...`.
Here are my headers for the CSV file:

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-encoding: UTF-8");
header("Content-dispositon: attachment; filename=name.csv");
```

Can anybody tell me how to solve both? I can only solve either one.

Comment: see this answer might help you -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576520/php-streaming-csv-always-adds-utf-8-bom

Comment: The above question seems not helpful.

Comment: My php file does not have BOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, without BOM:

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-dispositon: attachment; filename=name.csv");
```

And check if the data is really written in UTF-8, if you are using a latin1 database or an ISO/ANSI PHP script, use `utf8_encode` to convert the content before `echo`/`print` data.

Comment: Database too? try to utf8_encode the values for double check, sometimes the connection to database convert the values...

Comment: Nope, it is totally not relevant to the database as I merely output a csv file with content disposition attachment.

Comment: By the way, the csv file outputs with encoding UTF-8 without BOM too and I am wondering how to change it to without BOM with php.

Comment: To remove the file BOM, simply `substr($data,3)`. Sometimes the download happen in utf-8, but your application (after download) not read the file using the right encoding. OpenOffice and Excel read the files with different encodings by default.