# Unwanted blank characters at beginning of PHP stream

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to redirect a download from my site, basically reading a remote stream and echoing it from my site (this was a utility I quickly developed when I needed a download to bypass a firewall).

Last I checked, this worked just fine. I wanted to add a functionality yesterday and discovered that the returned stream is now preceded by 4 blank characters. I can't understand where those come from. No matter what happens, the downloaded file always begins with  (4 spaces, ensured with 'view invisible characters' mode in Notepad++) and is unaltered otherwise.

[Edit] In answer to a comment: those spaces are *not* part of the original file. To test this behaviour, I downloaded the original file (a JPG for a simple test), then downloaded it through the proxy and diffed the two. 4 bytes difference, which can be resolved by removing the first four characters of the proxied file. Of course, until I resolve the diff, the proxied file is unusable.

[Edit2] Those characters do not appear to be a BOM either. Remember, there are 4 of them. [Wikipedia tells us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) an UTF-8 BOM would be 3-byte long:

> The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the byte sequence `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`. A text editor or web browser misinterpreting the text as ISO-8859-1 or CP1252 will display the characters `ï»¿` for this.

Now I can't think of any change I made in code which could explain this new behaviour. Maybe an update in PHP? I don't have a phpinfo on this server yet (will get one tonight), but this is running on an up-to-date Ubuntu 14.04.

I guess I'll have to tinker the code to solve it. Only I don't know how. Maybe someone would have a lead to try on?

Below is the code:

```
function download($url, $filename, $mimetype) {
    /* prepare filename */
    // [prepare $filename]

    // mess with the headers to bypass the proxy
    header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype['mime']);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

    // and now the file content
    IOUtils::readfile($url);
}
```

In IOUtils:

```
<?php

/**
 * Static utilities for IO.
 *
 * @author Cyrille Chopelet
 */
class IOUtils {

    /**
     * Copies the content of the file as a stream into the response stream.
     * <p>
     * This could seem to be a useless override for the PHP readfile function,
     * but this is bufferized so that available memory is not overflowed
     * when reading a large file.
     *
     * @param string $path the URI to the file
     */
    public static function readfile($path) {
        $handle = fopen($path, 'rb');
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            echo fread($handle, 8192);
            ob_flush();
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

}

?>
```

No output is done before calling the `download` function. This would obviously fail otherwise since `header` cannot be called once output has started. This means this seems to happen while reading the `$handle` or writing it to the stream.

Comment: Just making sure - there's no other call or commands prior to calling the`download` function?

Comment: I just checked that this morning. Nope, no other call. The file begins immediately with the `<?php` and there is nothing before. For proof, I have no error when calling the `header()` functions.

Comment: Maybe there are spaces in the beginning of downloadable file?

Comment: Nope, I checked that by downloading a JPG: I had the original one and the one that went through the proxy. The proxied one is corrupt. Using a diff, I found the four blanks at the start, removed them, and then both files were the same. That my proxy now corrupts data is beyond doubt. I just need to understand _why_ and how to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure they're spaces and not BOM? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576520/php-streaming-csv-always-adds-utf-8-bom?rq=1

Comment: From [the Wikipedia page about BOMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark): "The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the byte sequence `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`. A text editor or web browser misinterpreting the text as ISO-8859-1 or CP1252 will display the characters `ï»¿` for this." Notepad++ showed me 4 (not 3) spaces (I actually showed invisible characters to make sure they were spaces since BOM was my first idea too).

Comment: @downvoter I don't mind being downvoted when deserved. Just tell me what I did wrong so I will not make the same mistakes next time. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you replace `IOUtils::readfile($url);` with `readfile($url)`? If this works it would be a strong indication that the problem is really caused by stream handling.

Comment: Are the 4 additional chars at the beginning of your downloads always the same? If so, which bytes are prepended?

Comment: @maxhb Using PHP's `readfile`, I get only 3 spaces instead of 4. The characters are always the same (`20 20 20` for `readfile($url)`, `20 20 20 20` for `IOUtils::readfile($url)`).

Comment: Try adding ob_clean(); to the beginning IOUtils::readfile(). May be there is already something in the ob.

Comment: This seems to do the trick, though I don't know what may have been buffered. Can you post an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above, my guess is that:

1. Automatic [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) is enabled.
2. Some file is sending output, maybe whitespace characters before the opening tag `<?`.

Because of output buffering, calls to `header()` will not fail. To find where the output is sent, try flushing all active output buffers before your calls to `header()` using the following code

```
while (@ob_end_flush())
    ;
```

And if warnings are enabled, you should see something similar to this:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at path/to/file.php:1)
```

If you dont see any warnings, check your `error_reporting`, `error_log` and `display_errors` settings.

Comment: Now that's interesting. Searching the configuration, the automatic buffering is active. I have a minification script that I apply to PHP. I deactivated it to understand which line the output started from (otherwise: `headers already sent by (output started at /var/.../downloader.php:1)`) and this solved the problem. I'll stop at that. Something when my PHP is minified causes an early output, though I don't know why the logic should be impacted. Thanks anyway!